# How can relative entropy be a measure of how well a candidate model approximates the unknown true data generating model if the true model is unknown?

Tags: statistics, information-theory, entropy

I have a decent understanding of most of the general idea of relative entropy(Kullback-Liebler Divergence). However I would like help clarifying the following from a set of notes:

" Relative entropy measures good a candidate model $M_k$ is as an approximation for the typically unknown true data generating model $M_{\text{true}}$".

My question is: **How can we measure how well a model approximates the true model if the true model is unknown 
?**

Edit: Is it that we collect samples from the true distribution, calculate an estimate of the true distribution(the empirical distribution) and then to compute the expectations with respect to the true distribution in fact compute averages using the empirical distribution

Comment: Note that the function makes sense whether you know $M_{\mathrm{true}}$ or not. So I'm guessing you mean 'how can I compute this'. The answer is using data, of course. You might propose a model $M_k$ which you know, and collect samples from $M_{\mathrm{true}}$. Then if you can estimate $D(M_k \| M_{\mathrm{true}})$ or $D(M_{\mathrm{true}}\|M_k)$ (depending on what you're doing) using these samples (with confidence bounds), you get an idea of how well $M_k$ approximates the truth. Estimation of KL divergence is a subtle problem, but good estimators do exist.

Comment: How does the function make sense whether we know $M_{true}$ or not if we have to take the expectation with respect to the true distribution ?

Comment: Also do we collect samples to estimate $M_{true}$'s distribution? (and if we did this wouldn't we just use this estimated distribution and skip the whole minimising of the relative entropy?)

Comment: Do we use the empirical distribution of F as an estimate?

Comment: Suppose I tell you that there's some distribution out there, which is supported on a finite number of naturals. Does $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim P}[X]$ make sense? This is a very typical notion of a quantity we can't compute, but often can estimate (say by taking samples means for a dataset of iid observations drawn from P).

Comment: Now, here's a small twist - I tell you a priori that the true mean is a whole number. Is the sample mean still a good estimate of the true mean of our unknown $P$? Maybe you'd round the value a bit? The point is that further information about the unknown object changes the sort of estimates we may make of it. Hence the KL divergence as an objective function - although we may use the empirical law of $M_{\mathrm{true}},$ we might have extra information that can't directly be incorporated into the empirical law. Or we might be interested in best appx to...

Comment: $M_{\mathrm{true}}$ in some restricted class of models. Or something else. Minimising KL divergence is one principled way to select the most appropriate $M_k$ to model $M_{\mathrm{true}}$ with all this extra stuff around. Depending on context, you may simply plug in an empirical dist. of $M_{\mathrm{true}}.$ Or some tweaked version of it. There's huge breadth - this is getting close to the foundational problems of statistics, and there's obviously no clean answer. You may want to search for, e.g., variational Bayes methods (Wainwright + Jordan have a decent monograph) for some perspective.